# Access combo-box in data template WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I wanna access combo-box though my c# code by its name,
as i can set the selected-index property of that combo-box.

### [image]

specifically, i have data-grid  which has two columns as combo-box:
first one refers to the expire date of a product
the second refers to the amount of that product

if the user change the expire date in the first combo-box automatically 
the amount in the other combo-box changes to its relative expire date

how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can SelectedItem and bind it with TwoWay mode to a property.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

c#

```
  private Object myItem;
    public Object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return myItem; }
        set
        {
            myItem = value;
            ItemChanged(myItem); // Function to be called
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Stamos, I get it and it worked fine... I had bind the selected index of the amount to property which refers to the index of the selected item of the expire date column

Comment: You are welcome @Wael Mourad SelectedIndex works fine as well. The difference is that by SelectedItem you can cast the object to its original model that in some cases makes your life easier. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.